# How to disable save icon in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Can someone help me in disabling save icon on a window in Oracle Forms? I am talking about one of the Save icon/button in the menu bar.

thanks

Comment: Use `set_menu_item_property`?

Comment: that's correct.. but what is the menu id of save icon? that I do not know

Answer (score 0):

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2355328?tstart=0

Found this little bit for you. Hope it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the functionality of that item.
When you press save button, KEY-COMMIT trigger gets fired.
So you just type the following line on KEY-COMMIT Trigger :

```
null;
```

This will just do nothing when you press the save button from the default menu.